# signedIn property of domHost is false on ready function call

Tags: polymer, firebase-authentication

I want to check if the user is logged in on element creation and eventually redirect him if the user is not. The problem is that the domHost.signedIn property is false even though the user is signedIn. If I check the property later(for example when I call a function with button tap) the property  is true as it should be.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="settings-view">
    <template>
        <style>
        </style>
        TODO: user settings
        <paper-button on-tap="debugFunction">button</paper-button>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'settings-view',

            ready: function () {
                console.log(this.domHost.signedIn); // false
                console.log(this.domHost.user);  // null
            },

            debugFunction: function () {
                console.log(this.domHost.signedIn); // true
                console.log(this.domHost.user); // user object
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

What is the best way to check if the user is signedIn in child element? Would setting the signedIn value to iron-meta element be a better approach?

Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 2):

You're better off declaring properties with [observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers) on them. Observers will execute the function as soon as the property's value is something other than `undefined`. So your code will look like this:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="settings-view">
    <template>
        <style>
        </style>
        TODO: user settings
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'settings-view',

            properties: {
                signedIn: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    observer: '_signedInChanged'
                },

                user: {
                    type: Object,
                    observer: '_userChanged'
                },
            },

            _signedInChanged: function (newSignedInValue) {
                console.log(newSignedInValue); // true
                console.log(this.signedIn); // true
            },

            _userChanged: function (newUserValue) {
                console.log(newUserValue); // user object
                console.log(this.user); // user object
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Then when you update those `signedIn` and `user` values through JavaScript or data binding, the observers will call the associated functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer but there is a problem that the _signedInChanged and _userChanged functions are firstly called with false and null value and then with true and user object. I would like to redirect user to login page if the value signedIn was false. So it doesn't solve my problem since I would redirect them in the first function call. I tried to set the default value to true, but it didn't help. Thanks