# Effective way to share user and auth reference across the app

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

I am creating an app using Polymer and Polymerfire elements and I can't find an effective way to share user and auth references across the app.

My current solution of receiving auth reference is as follows:

```
var auth = document.getElementById('appID').app.auth()
```

This approach works but I have a hunch that there should be a better way.

Second problem is, that I am not sure howto get the user reference in subviews, were getting the reference by property sharing would be super cumbersome(and I've been having issues using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729512/signedin-property-of-domhost-is-false-on-ready-function-call/40734417#40734417)).

I was thinking that using iron-meta tag might solve the issue, but that would mean that on every login and logout I would have to set the value "manually". So is there a more straightforward way to share the reference?

If I access the firebase-auth reference directly:

```
document.getElementById('authID').user
```

Then there is a problem that when it's accessed in the element's ready function call it's always null. If it's called later, then it works fine but I need to check if the user is logged in in ready call(and redirect to login page).

Plus, this approach doesn't work at all if global Polymer setting is set to: dom: 'shadow' (The firebase-auth is not located in index.html but lower and with this setting I am able to access only the index.html elements.) and this setting is supposed to be set by default in the future and I want the solution to be future-proofed.

I'll be grateful for any responses, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Apparently it's possible to initialize the firebase-auth element wherever you want and the element retains the app state as long as the app name is provided.

```
<firebase-auth id="auth" app-name=name-of-the-app"></firebase-auth>
```

Than just use the element reference:

```
this.$.auth
```

Answer (score 0):

The polymer fire element created by the polymer team will solve all your problems.

It's divided into the following elements:
firebase-auth
firebase-app
firebase-document
firebase-query
firebase-messaging

[Video Tutorial Authentication with Firebase -- Polycasts #57](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkhCs-IDgS4&t=4s)

[Official Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire)

Comment: I already use the polymerfire elements. My problem was I didn't know how to access them globally. I solved the issue by multiple uses of firebase-auth element.